# How to compare two excel sheets and insert into a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have two excel worksheets. In my first worksheet I have two columns `id` and `English Word`. In my second worksheet I have two columns `id` and `Arabic Word`. The `id` column in both worksheets contains same data. But all the `id` in English worksheet are not present in Arabic worksheet. But all the `id` in Arabic worksheet are present in English worksheet. I need to add a third column `Arabic Word` in my first worksheet which contains the arabic values from second worksheet comparing the `id`. If an `id` in English worksheet is not present in Arabic worksheet I would like the third column to be blank for that row. 
How can I do this using excel formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the appropriate changes in the formula below.
Sheet2!B:B is the list of Arabic Words. A2 is the id on the English sheet and Sheet2!A:A is the list of ids on the Arabic sheet.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"")
```